# How to iterate a mongo db document and update a nested array

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query

I need to remove entries inside a 2d array of documents structure in mongodb.

Sample is as below

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ffef283f1f06ff8524aa2c2"),
    "applicationName" : "TestApp",
    "pName" : "",
    "environments" : [],
    "stages" : [],
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2021-01-15T09:51:35.546Z"),
    "workflows" : [ 
        [ 
            {
                "pName" : "Test1",
                "wName" : "TestApp_Test1",
                "agent" : ""
            }, 
            {
                "pName" : "Test2",
                "wName" : "TestApp_Test2",
                "agent" : ""
            }
        ], 
        [ 
            {
                "pName" : "Test1",
                "wName" : "TestApp_Test1",
                "agent" : ""
            }
        ]
    ],
    "updatedAt" : Date(-62135596800000)
}
```

So, I want to remove all document occurences of

```
{
  "pName" : "Test1",
  "wName" : "TestApp_Test1",
  "agent" : ""
}
```

from both the arrays.

**pName:Test1** can be used to filter it out.

What's the query which can be used to find this and delete it ?

I am ok to do a find and then iterate over the collection , find the matching entry and then update the document. I have to do this using Go mongodb driver

Since this is kind of complex for me as I am new to both golang and mongo db, I am stuck.

Update:
1.Tried `{$pull: {workflows: {pName:"Test1"}}}, {multi: true}` in the update() call as suggested but didn't work.

2.Tried something like this

```
db.getCollection('workflows').update({_id:ObjectId('5ffef283f1f06ff8524aa2c2')}, {$pull:{workflows: { $elemMatch: {pName:'Test2'}}}} )
```

This is removing the entire array as shown below because **Test2** is present in that. I need to remove only the Test2 document

```
[ 
    {
        "pName" : "Test1",
        "wName" : "TestApp_Test1",
        "agent" : ""
    }, 
    {
        "pName" : "Test2",
        "wName" : "TestApp_Test2",
        "agent" : ""
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give you a hint as you are new and you haven't posted the tried things.

You could use `$pull` to remove documents matching the conditions.

[similar example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121758/using-mongodb-pull-to-delete-documents-within-an-array)

And you could use [official mongodb driver](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/go/) for go or most used [gopkg](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2)

[An example SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35638441/mongodb-pull-success-indicator-with-mgo-golang)

Comment: Thanks. I tried {$pull: {workflows: {pName:"Test1"}}}, {multi: true} in the update() call. It said it updated in the mongo client but it didn't remove the entry. I know this needs a modification since its another enclosing array. How do we do it in this case ?

Comment: Alternatively, you can iterate by simple find and update workflows after removing programmatically.